# Crawling IMDB for movie trailers?

Tags: python, youtube, web-crawler

I want to crawl IMDB and download the trailers of movies (either from YouTube or IMDB) that fit some criteria (e.g.: released this year, with a rating above 2).

I want to do this in Python - I saw that there were packages for crawling IMDB and downloading YouTube videos. The thing is, my current plan is to crawl IMDB and then search youtube for '$movie_name' + 'trailer' and hope that the top result is the trailer, and then download it.

Still, this seems a bit convoluted and I was wondering if there was perhaps an easier way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is no easier way.** I doubt IMDB allows people to scrap their website freely so your IP is probably gonna get blacklisted and to counter that you'll need proxies. Good luck and scrape respectfully.

**EDIT**: Please take a look at @pds's answer below. My answer is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

This will provide the video link for you.
like this

[Video Link](https://imdb-video.media-imdb.com/vi1143521817/1434659529640-260ouz-1658337157882.mp4?Expires=1659400269&Signature=rtVqCLUbKKMywNiCP6Zfq7PVtnh5K-iWkqNt5Z93qKaKCzXKuzVscUFxyQjX2yLJnq5o4uv%7EYuoDgn1rMbgB3LdRnlNHYC6b1eRtQprIRE2S3e7XpZX%7E1S%7ETbKh%7E4cgfB%7EvyzJadLIJyHmcvIGt13FpBm-43%7EV6Kgarj9PZtWI5mxP7Ys3BMGM51Pho51JDaLoCqSfxTZ852H-g191vaE95swzQjZdGwP%7EO2zyjxiNwJ470h20NjNS1NF9zAlZ74N3mz4nkxSjTwE0BDonMCoy2xeohuiY7lVaTZ1qKm7%7EY9g3zJAnXludbo8ffj8BDoNk8zAHuzI8iRn-Lof2P1rQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFLZBVQZ24NQH3KA)

The following code parses the HTML source file of this [video page](https://www.imdb.com/video/vi3877612057/).
The mp4 link is here in the HTML source file. You can view the source file and search ".mp4"

The links are in `<script type="application/json"> json file having links </script>`

Each link expires in 1-2 hours, so you may download from the link instead of saving the links in a file or you can just run the script every time.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
video_id = "vi2766453273"
video_url = "https://www.imdb.com/video/"+video_id
print(video_url)

r = requests.get(url=video_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
script =soup.find("script",{'type': 'application/json'})
json_object = json.loads(script.string)
print(json_object["props"]["pageProps"]["videoPlaybackData"]["video"]["playbackURLs"])

videos = json_object["props"]["pageProps"]["videoPlaybackData"]["video"]["playbackURLs"]
# links video quality order auto,1080,720
for video in videos[1:] :
    video_link = video["url"]
    print(video_link)  
    #break
```

Checkout the full code at [GitHub](https://github.com/pavan412kalyan/imdb-movie-scraper/blob/main/downloaders/trailer_downloader/getTrailerByImdb.py#L77-L92)

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

The `imdbpy` API https://imdbpy.github.io/ will get you started, it's very straightforward.

```
  import imdb # pip install IMDbPY
  ia = imdb.IMDb()
  list_of_movies = ia.search_movie("string text")
  [ia.(m, info=['main','votes']) for m in list_of_movies[:1]]
  for m in list_of_movies[:1]:
    yt_search_term = m.get("name") + "trailer"
    # connect to YT API to start that part of the search.
```

Then lookup how to connect to the YTv3 API with appropriate authentication and download the corresponding Google client API - [Sample code here](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/search.py)

**Issues:** One challenge is that movie titles are not unique, so searching YT by `name+" trailer"` will not necessarily return your intended trailer. So you'll need to account for that somehow. For new hollywood blockbusters (and similar), you may be successful.

**Legal:** As indicated by the other answer, do verify your use case is in compliance with  the **terms and conditions and licenses** of the technologies and information services that you are using. If in doubt seek the approval from those parties first or seek professional legal advice.